# @asyncio.coroutine vs async def

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-3.5, python-asyncio

With the `asyncio` library I've seen,

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def function():
    ...
```

and

```
async def function():
    ...
```

used interchangeably.

Is there any functional difference between the two?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, there are functional differences between native coroutines using `async def` syntax and generator-based coroutines using the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator.

According to [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#differences-from-generators), which introduces the `async def` syntax:

> 1. *Native coroutine* objects do not implement `__iter__` and
>      `__next__` methods. Therefore, they cannot be iterated over or passed
>      to `iter()`, `list()`, `tuple()` and other built-ins. They also
>      cannot be used in a `for..in` loop.
>
>    An attempt to use `__iter__` or `__next__` on a native coroutine
>      object will result in a TypeError .
> 2. *Plain generators* cannot `yield from` *native coroutines*: doing so
>      will result in a TypeError .
> 3. *generator-based coroutines* (for asyncio code must be decorated with
>      `@asyncio.coroutine`) can `yield from` *native coroutine objects*.
> 4. `inspect.isgenerator()` and `inspect.isgeneratorfunction()` return `False` for *native coroutine* objects and *native coroutine functions*.

Point 1 above means that while coroutine functions defined using the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator syntax can behave as traditional generator functions, those defined with the `async def` syntax cannot.

Here are two minimal, ostensibly equivalent coroutine functions defined with the two syntaxes:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def decorated(x):
    yield from x 

async def native(x):
    await x
```

Although the bytecode for these two functions is almost identical:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(decorated)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 YIELD_FROM
              8 POP_TOP
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(native)
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 GET_AWAITABLE
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 YIELD_FROM
              8 POP_TOP
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

... the only difference being `GET_YIELD_FROM_ITER` vs `GET_AWAITABLE`, they behave completely differently when an attempt is made to iterate over the objects they return:

```
>>> list(decorated('foo'))
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

```
>>> list(native('foo'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable
```

Obviously `'foo'` is not an awaitable, so the attempt to call `native()` with it doesn't make much sense, but the point is hopefully clear that the `coroutine` object it returns is not iterable, regardless of its argument.

A more detailed investigation of the `async`/`await` syntax by Brett Cannon: [How the heck does async/await work in Python 3.5?](http://www.snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5) covers this difference in more depth.

Comment: Thanks! But why `inspect.iscoroutinefunction()` return `False` for native coroutine functions?

Comment: @roachsinai it [doesn't](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.iscoroutinefunction).

Answer (score 22):

`async def` is a new syntax from Python 3.5.
You could use `await`, `async with` and `async for` inside `async def`s.

`@coroutine` is a functional analogue for `async def` but it works in Python 3.4+ and utilizes `yield from` construction instead of `await`.

For practical perspective just never use `@coroutine` if your Python is 3.5+.

Comment: Would be good to know why exactly "never use @coroutine" in 3.5+. Is there a real reason or is it an opinion/rule of thumb? For example, I have some @coroutine decorators in a 3.4 inherited codebase but all new development is in 3.5. Should I be turning those decorators into `async def`?

Comment: To suspend coroutine execution it is necessary to `yield`. But `yield` is not allowed from inside native coroutines! So looks like it's still necessary to use `@coroutine` even in Python 3.5+

Comment: No. Just use `await asyncio.sleep(0)`.

Comment: @hmijail `@coroutine` marked generators could be awaited but better to convert them into `async def` if possible.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov `asyncio.sleep` must be using `yield` somewhere inside, doesn't it? So, `@coroutine`'s wouldn't be gone from the language. But I agree that if you are using `asyncio` or some other framework you do not have to (and most probably should not) use `@coroutine`.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(10)` works pretty well. Moreover I've converted `asyncio.sleep()` into `async def` in asyncio master (will be released as part of Python 3.7).

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov This is really interesting! How that would work? As far as I understand, sooner or later `yield` must be called to yield control, so somewhere deep inside `@coroutine` must be used. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From *Python 3.5* `coroutines` formally became a distinct type and thus the `async def` syntax, along with `await` statements.

Prior to that, *Python 3.4* created coroutines by wrapping regular functions into `generators`, hence the decorator syntax, and the more generator-like `yield from`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.4, when native coroutines were not available, asynchronous programming was implemented using `@asyncio.coroutine` which uses `yield from` syntax to pause and resume generators to perform asynchronous tasks.

However, in Python 3.5, the concept of native coroutines was introduced, which uses `async def` to define coroutine which can be paused by using `await`. This allows for efficient suspension of execution without blocking the event loop, hence enhancing performance.

Therefore, `async def` becomes the new standard and preferred way to perform asynchronous tasks.

Here's a simple asynchronous function:

```
async def my_coroutine():
    await fetch_db_record()  # some asynchronous function
```