# tkinter use yield from in button command

Tags: python, tkinter, discord.py

I am using Tkinter and discord.py together, and I want it to change the user's nickname on the press of a button. to change the nickname, discord.py uses the command `yield from client.change_nickname(server.me, string)`
but when I run that code in the command of a button, the function never get's ran. I have used a print statement to make sure, and none of the function gets ran. I have tried to use multi-threading to start the function, and that didn't work, any help would be appreciated

```
async def test2():
    server = client.get_server("345548250432012298")
    await client.change_nickname(server.me, "testing")
def test():
    threading.Thread(target=test2).start()
def makeThing(nicks):
    frame = Tk()
    for i in range(0, len(nicks)):
        Button(frame, text=nicks[i], command= test).grid(row=i)
    frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you need asyncio to start an asynchronous event loop to be able to call a coroutine, though, I might be wrong..

Comment: kinda new ti asyncio, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to call an `async def` coroutine using the `threading` module. To make this work, you'll need to use `asyncio` to run an event loop in your `test` function. Assuming you don't care about the implications of a long-running call in your main thread, you can just directly use `run_until_complete`.

```
import asyncio

async def test2():
    server = client.get_server("345548250432012298")
    await client.change_nickname(server.me, "testing")
def test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  
    loop.run_until_complete(test2())
    loop.close()  
def makeThing(nicks):
    frame = Tk()
    for i in range(0, len(nicks)):
        Button(frame, text=nicks[i], command= test).grid(row=i)
    frame.mainloop()
```

If you need to make more async calls in one event loop, use `ensure_future` instead. Do note that you can break the async call off into its own thread using `threading` (as you correctly surmised) as long as you call the `run_until_complete` in the thread.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270790/4504895) should help you use threads with asyncio (in that answer, `@asyncio.coroutine` is generally equivalent to `async def` [but there do exist some differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571786/asyncio-coroutine-vs-async-def)) and this [async/await tutorial](http://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/) should serve you well for general learning.

Comment: this works slightly better, but i am getting the error "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running" this is the only asyncio function i am calling. it may be discord.py using an event loop. i tried putting it into a seperate thread, and got the same error. i dont know where i would put the "ensure future" command

Comment: @TylerSilva You're right, they do have their own event loop. I'll edit this in a little bit but you should use `client.loop.create_task` to use their event loop (`client.loop` if you'd prefer to just have the loop) source: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py

Comment: now it doesnt change the nickname until after i close the tkinter window. there are no errors, just waits until you xit out of the tkinter window to run the code