# “async with” in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

The Getting Started docs for asyncssh give the following hello example:

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys

async def run_client():
    async with asyncssh.connect('localhost') as conn:
        result = await conn.run('echo "Hello!"', check=True)
        print(result.stdout, end='')

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client())
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
    sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
```

However, this will not run, because async with is not supported in Python 3.4:

```
async with asyncssh.connect('localhost', username='squirtle', password='xxxxxxxxxxxx') as conn:
     ^
```

Comment: please ask another question with your edit, so we can keep the questions clean

Comment: I've removed the edit and made a new question.

Comment: consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and did it, this works for me.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def run_client():
        with(yield from asyncssh.connect('localhost', username='root', password='xxxxxxxx')) as conn:
                result = yield from conn.run('ls', check=True)
                print(result.stdout, end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

`async` keyword was introduced in **Python 3.5**, you should use `asyncio.corutine` in earlier versions.

Check [PEP492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) and [Python 3.5 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#summary-release-highlights)

Also you would like to check this [SO Question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571786/asyncio-coroutine-vs-async-def)