# capture stdout and stderr of process that runs an infinite loop

Tags: python

I want to run a process that runs an infinite loop (for example, starting a database server) from a python script and capture stdout and stderr. I tried this, but `p.communicate()` never returns, apparently because the process needs to finish first.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
cmd = "python infinite_loop.py"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print("the process is running")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

I'd like to get the output in some kind of streaming form. For example, I might want to save every 100 characters to a new log file. How can I do it?

Comment: I feel like I've done this with [asyncio.subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html), but I unfortunately don't have a code sample for you.  (Following [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-using-streams) specifically).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Something closer to what you already had, as asyncio seems like overkill for a single coroutine:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

args = (sys.executable, '-u', 'test4.py')
cmd = ' '.join(args)
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
print("the process is running")

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
    line = line.rstrip()
    print(line)
```

---

**Original:**

I threw something together.  The following uses [`asyncio.subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) to read lines from a subprocess' output, and then do something with them (in this case, just `print()` them).

The subprocess is specified by `args`, and in my case is just running another python instance in unbuffered mode with the following script (test4.py):

```
import time
for _ in range(10):
    print(time.time(), flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm sleeping in the `for` loop so it's clear whether the lines are coming in individually or all at once when the program has finished.  (If you don't believe me, you can change the `for` loop to `while True:`, which will never finish).

The "supervisor" script is:

```
import asyncio.subprocess
import sys


async def get_lines(args):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    while proc.returncode is None:
        data = await proc.stdout.readline()
        if not data: break
        line = data.decode('ascii').rstrip()
        # Handle line (somehow)
        print(line)


if sys.platform == "win32":
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
else:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

args = (sys.executable, '-u', 'test4.py')
loop.run_until_complete(get_lines(args))
loop.close()
```

Note that `async def` is Python 3.5+, [but you could use `@asyncio.coroutine` in 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571786/asyncio-coroutine-vs-async-def).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If you try to call any of the Python subprocess functions to read the outputs of another infinite or hanging process, the Python parent process will just freeze as well because Python seems to be trying to read to the end of output, which is never because it is an infinite loop.